# Can we customize calendar widget in such a way that DAY bar comes vertically in a column?

Tags: android, calendar, widget, customization

I am really stuck in this. I want to customize the calendar widget in which dates come in a vertical arrangement and days name come in the first column.

[image: Sample calendar image]